# Test Class for Custom Controller Example

Tags: apex, unit-test

Hi I'm hoping someone can help, I have a custom controller with a simple SQL statement that I can't seem to get a test class working, here is the controller:

```java
public class Example_Controller {
    
public Example__c ExampleFields { get; set; }
    
    public Example_Controller() {
        ExampleFields = [SELECT Id, Site__r.Name, Issue_No__c,Site__r.Account.Name,Quote__r.Name,Compliance_Sheet_Design_Ref__c,Example_Checked_By__c,Example_Prepared_By__c,Work_Area__c FROM RAMS__c 
                   WHERE Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];
    }
}
```

Here is my test class which returns zero test coverage:

```java
@isTest(SeeAllData=true)
public class Example_ControllerTest {
    @istest
    public static void testCurrentExample(){

        Pricebook2  standardPb = [select id, name, isActive from Pricebook2 where IsStandard = true limit 1];
    
        Product2 prod = new Product2(Name='test1',Family='Liner', IsActive=true);
        insert prod;
    
        PricebookEntry pbe = new PricebookEntry (Product2Id=prod.id,Pricebook2ID=standardPb.id,UnitPrice=50, isActive=true);
        insert pbe;
        
        Opportunity o = new Opportunity(Name='Testing Opportunity', StageName='New', CloseDate=system.today());
        insert o; 
        
        Quote q = new Quote(Name='Test', Pricebook2Id = standardPb.id, OpportunityId=o.id);
        insert q; 
        
        Example__c ExampleFields = new Example__c(Issue_No__c='0001',Example_Prepared_By__c='Jack',Example_Checked_By__c='Tom',Compliance_Sheet_Design_Ref__c='3121',Site__c=o.id,Work_Area__c='Hospital Building',Quote__c=q.id);
        insert ExampleFields;
        
        //ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(ExampleFields);
        //Apexpages.StandardController sc = new Apexpages.StandardController(ExampleFields);
        //Example_Controller ext = new Example_Controller (sc);
        //Example_Controller  a=new Example_Controller ();
        //ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(ExampleFields);

        //Example_Controller controller = new Example_Controller (sc);

        List <Example__c> Example = [SELECT id,Issue_No__c,Example_Prepared_By__c,Example_Checked_By__c,Compliance_Sheet_Design_Ref__c,Site__c,Work_Area__c,Quote__c FROM Example__c WHERE Id = :ExampleFields.Id];

        System.assertequals('0001', Example[0].Issue_No__c);
        

    }
}
```

Comment: you have a lot of issues here - start by reviewing https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.238.0.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_error_handling.htm?q=testing and then [edit] with revised code. You do not need `seeAllData=TRUE` which is bad practice and applies only in very unusual circumstances

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, I needed to put the page in to test and then 'create' a new controller:

```
PageReference pageRef = Page.Example
pageRef.getParameters().put('id', String.valueOf(ExampleFields.Id));
Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef); 
Example_Controller testAccPlan = new Example_Controller();
Test.StopTest();
```